# cannot switch the value of the variable in python

Tags: python, variables

```
act = 0
Muscle_Input = input("Please input muscle you wish to activate: ")
if Muscle_Input == ["a", "A"]:
    act = 1
elif Muscle_Input == ["b", "B",]:
    act = 2
print(act)
```

I planned to use the variable switch to activate while loops, but every time I attempt to run the script It refuses to change the "act" variable from 0.

Comment: `Muscle_Input == ["a", "A"]` you're checking to see if your input equals a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input returns a string.

Muscle_Input therefore will NEVER `== ["a", "A"]` (since that is a list)

instead try

```
if Muscle_Input in ("a", "A"):
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was very confused about this problem and it now works.

Comment: Great- if it solved your problem, feel free to mark the question as solved ;) Welcome to stackoverflow